# How can i fetch blogger posts in SearchView using retrofit library

Tags: android, retrofit2, blogger

How can I fetch blogger posts in android search view using a retrofit library, I am searching for this from many days but not found in google please help me.

Comment: This cannot be done!
However you can post a `JSONObject` request and then retrieve the information and show it `Recycler View`. Then set the search view with a adapter to filter the items in accordance the text entered by the user.
I personally use and recommend `Volley` instead of `Retrofit` as it is more easy to use

Comment: yes but I have build app in a retrofit library, I have tried recycler view filter for search view but not showing all posts in search

Comment: no. it's not clear can I post my code here.

Comment: will you please check this video i am facing this https://youtu.be/-_AaEjsWuog

Comment: your adapter working fine but i have to fetch posts from json and show in recyclerview

Comment: this is my adapter please check this [adapter]https://pastebin.com/raw/yqJT5PdU

Comment: please check this video you will know the exact problem I am facing, actually, I am a beginner in android so it looks difficult to me, that's y spending to much time on this things. [link]https://youtu.be/-_AaEjsWuog

Comment: no sir just fetching preloaded items not fetching from json...